# Moving an image to the position of the mouse?

Tags: javascript

Very Very new to Javascript, just trying to learn :)

What I want to do is have an image (will ultimately be a sprite) at default location, then when I click the right mouse button on the screen, I want the image to gradually move to that location?

I did some research but couldn't find this specifically.

Ultimately I want to have a animated game character that I can move on the screen using the right mouse button.

Comment: You should look into using the jQuery and jQuery UI Frameworks  jquery.com

Comment: Generally, right mouse button is bound to displaying context menus and overriding it is a good way to annoy the user. The possibility to hide default context menu can be disabled by the user in his browser settings, and doing something on right click while still displaying the menu is not the most pretty thing. So, I recommend to change the behavior to be on left-mouse double click or some other event.

Answer (score 6):

Like everyone else said stay away from right click, heres an example using jQuery.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/S4TfC/1/)**

```
var $follower = $("#follower"),
    mouseX = 0, 
    mouseY = 0;

$(document).click(function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
   $follower.stop().animate({left : mouseX, top: mouseY});
});
```

and pure JS *updated 2017 to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`*

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/S4TfC/426/)**

```
var mouseX = 0, 
    mouseY = 0,
    follower = document.getElementById("follower"),
    xp = 0,
    yp = 0;

document.onclick = function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
};

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
    follower.style.left = xp + 'px';
    follower.style.top= yp + 'px';
}

animate();
```

Comment: This is very good stuff, thus, a late upvote, especially the pure JS animate function is a piece of art, it's unintentionally a great showcase of recursive fn calls and setTimeout:-)

Comment: @ptts thanks for the kind comment, I actually just updated the fiddle and answer due to it to reflect what I would use now, http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/S4TfC/426/ `requestAnimationFrame` should be used over settimout, however in 2011 that wasn't the case quite yet.

Answer (score 2):

Last I checked, there isn't a reliable and cross-browser way to handle right-clicking, so I'd advise you stay with a left-click. Given you are very very new to Javascript, you'd probably want to use jQuery. For animating the object on the screen, I'd point you to [jQuerys animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) where they have examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using the right mouse click if you can. I found support in Firefox and Chrome, but had problems with IE.

If you went with a left click, I would use the jQuery framework (http://jquery.com/).

You can add catch the click anywhere on the page, then get the coordinates from the event. Using the coordinates, you can then change the CSS of the element you want to move:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(document).click(function(e){

        $('#element').animate( { "top": e.pageY + "px" }, { queue: false, duration: 1500 }).animate({ "left": e.pageX + "px" }, 1500 );

    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="element" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:red; position:absolute;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I'd agree that messing with the right mouse button is a bad idea.  But in the case of making a game, taking control of the RMB is actually perfectly acceptable, if not desired.  Most of the reasons for taking control of the RMB go away in this situation, and it can be used to increase the functionality of the game (the reason the user is on the page in the first place), as opposed to taking away functionality (the common reason behind not messing with the RMB).

That said, jQuery is not the best option at all for this sort of thing.  It's just not geared towards game development.  Instead, look into html5 game development.  There's a few different game engines out there that make this sort of thing easy, and the best list of resources at the moment is the [HTML5 Games Resource Section](http://html5games.com/resources/)

[Construct2](http://www.scirra.com/construct2) doesn't even require much programming understanding at all!

Comment: It's true that it could be acceptable in certain cases, however it doesn't change the fact that it's not reliable. In Firefox one can set `dom.event.contextmenu.enabled` to false (in options available as `Allow scripts to disable or replace context menu`), in Opera right-click menu doesn't work even in Google Maps. But of course everything depends on the target group etc.

Comment: @jakub And that's why I suggest using a game engine library.  Most/all of them solve these sorts of issues, much like jQuery solves cross browser issues for other things (and why everyone is recommending it)